# Text file auto-loading incorrectly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, table, corrupt

In QGIS 3.18. I have a tab-separated text file (.txt) loaded as a table. This table serves as the layer reference for the Value Relation widget for several fields (that is: the allowed check box values come from that table); therefore, the file is permanently loaded in my project.

The problem is that on a semi-regular basis, I notice that my check boxes are missing from the mentioned fields; I check Layer Properties-->Attributes Form-->Value Relation widget and the Column selectors are empty; I check the text layer, and the table is completely scrambled: both the column headers and the contents are incoherent (see image).
[image]

If I then delete and reupload the text file, it is correct again -- and is likely to remain correct the next several times I open the project... until one time it scrambles again.

This is the case for other text layers in my project as well.

Is this a known bug with tab-separated values files? Or, what could be the cause of the **occasional*** scrambling of the values? As far as I can tell there is no pattern to it; I do not receive error messages concerning the file loading, and I don't seem to have trouble with non-text layers.

Comment: For the why I have no answer, but if you dont need to keep your table as a text file I suggest that you export it to a more 'stable' format at last this should solve the issue

Comment: Thanks for the comment; what format would you suggest for being able to be referenced for a series of check boxes (Relational values widget)?

Comment: That will depend on how your other data are stored. If you use a database just add the table along the other data. If you use some file data format (or can't add to your database) you may try .gpkg, .dbf, in fact any table format that you can load directly in qgis should do the job

Answer (score 1):

There is a clear pattern visible: letter `t` (=tab?) is considered as field delimiter. Best convert the text first to an UTF-8 encoded CSV file, then import it as File Format CSV (comma separated values) or Custom Delimiters and only select the ones you need (Tab, Semicolon) - see screnshot.

Obviously, when importing the text, the charactet `t` is interpreted as a field delimiter and not as a letter (part of the text string). As can be seen on your screenshot is that everywhere where a `t` should appear, this letter lacks and the following text is shifted to the next field.

See the first line of your screenshot:

*How it looks like now:*
[image]

*How it should look:*

[image]

Reimport your text file and make sure to set the correct delimiters.

*Reprodcing the behaviour you encountered: `t` set as other delimiter character:*
[image]